# Setting up spring toolkit - spring classes not being found

Tags: eclipse, spring-ide

I've downloaded and installed the latest spring toolkit on eclipse helios via the update site. According to the spring website the toolkit contains "everything" needed to develop a spring app. All the spring imports are not found such as -

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
```

Compile error given is = "The import org.springframework cannot be resolved"

When I create a new spring project I would have thought all spring dependencies would have been added to my build path automatically, but checking project properties this does not seem to be the case. Do I need to explicitly add the required libraries and if so should they be available as part of the spring toolkit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required jars are available from http://www.springsource.com/download/community For spring3.1 their in spring-framework-3.1.0.RELEASE.zip

This tutorial is useful for setting up - http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Spring-30-Tutorial-Setting-Up-Configuring-The-Environment